# Reading a text file then setting as variables to use for authentication in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I am just seeing if I can get anything from the text file to show up on my website so I can work with it. I've checked multiple questions on here, but I feel like my lack of knowledge with web development is showing here.

So my javascript function is this...

```
function readTextFile(file)
{
var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
    if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
    {
        if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
        {
            var allText = rawFile.responseText;
          document.write(allText);
        }
    }
}
rawFile.send(null);
}
```

So ideally I would think that this would just write the text onto the page.
So I call it within the page like this...(I'm not terribly creative just thought this should work).

```
<body onload="readTextFile('info.txt')">
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Not sure if you can load *text* file directly as it would turn into security concerns for browsers. You can load in javascript files which could contain variables that you require.

Comment: At which browser are you trying code at Question?

Comment: homework assignment. Requirement is to get username and password info from a text file, however I'm asking this in a way so I don't directly get the answer since I should be able to figure out what to do when I get this working with a split.

Comment: browser isn't specified in the requirements unfortunately, but maybe chrome?

Comment: At chrome or chromium you would need to launch the browser with `--allow-file-access-from-files` flags set for ability to access `file:` protocol

Comment: Still not seeing any of the text file text posted on the website. Possibility that my code is wrong?

Comment: Okay, update it opens the file with microsoft edge, but not chrome. Thanks

Comment: Okay so it loads a whole page with the text file, however I want to keep the login page loaded and just want to pull the data from the text file and set it as variables.